# Synchronizing stateless EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, synchronization, ejb, memcached

I have a very specific problem. Hope someone can help me. 
My application uses memcached and stateless ejbs. User makes a request, ejb check cache for data, if there is a data user gets a data, if there is no data, ejb goes to DB and fetch data, put data into cache and return it to user.

Problem is if many users make a requests and cache is empty. First request will check a cache, there is no data and will go to DB to get it. Second, third and so on requests will also check for data in cache, and go to DB because first one didn't finished fetching.

Is there a way to just first requests go to DB and other requests wait for the first to return and put data into cache so other can get it from cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans#Singleton_Session_Beans) instead of Stateless EJBs to enforce having a single, unique instance per JVM. By default concurrent access to the Singleton EJB is managed by the container so synchronization is done for you.

More details: [Managing Concurrent Access in a Singleton Session Bean](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html)

Keep in mind that due to synchronization your application will perform and scale worse. Usually what you described is not really a problem, in case of empty cache multiple calls might hit the database but this cause no harm and rarely happens.